# Android app loading ARM shared library on x86 device fails

Tags: android, x86, arm, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I have a really simple android app. I want to load a shared library called 'libcamera.so' and then call methods via JNI.
I do not own this library and I do not have access to the source code. It was originally compiled for ARM. 
An x86 version is not available.

The project can detect the library and correctly shows it in the jniLibs folder.

Within my main activity I am trying to load the 3rd party library like so:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("camera");
}
```

When this line executes, logcat shows the following:

```
02-06 14:11:38.517 4455-4455/uk.co.test.myApp E/art: dlopen("/data/app/uk.co.test.myApp-2/lib/x86/libcamera.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: "/data/app/uk.co.test.myApp-2/lib/x86/libcamera.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
02-06 14:11:38.519 4455-4455/uk.co.test.myApp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: uk.co.test.myApp, PID: 4455
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/uk.co.test.myApp-2/lib/x86/libcamera.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40
     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
     at uk.co.test.myApp.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:17)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1603)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Other 3rd party apps which use this library can run on my x86 device (Epson BT350) so I feel like this should be possible. 
I have become aware of something called 'Houdini' which allows ARM apps to run on x86 - I have checked and my device has this library so im confused why its not doing its job. But its also quite likely I dont really understand how Houdini works!

I have tried running on an x86 emulator - same error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your APK contain a separate copy of the same (armeabi) libcamera.so under lib\x86? If so, have you tried simply not adding that additional copy? (i.e. only providing the library in lib\armeabi or lib\armeabi-v7a).

Comment: unfortunately not! Only armeabi

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by forcing my app to only build an armeabi version. I did this by using an abifilter within gradle. I added the following to my defaultConfig

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi"
}
```

This will then run on my x86 device because Houdini will kick in and do the translation. Its not ideal because this translation affects performance - but its a start and gets me to the next stage.